# Using VLAN, IP A shows (and uses) also raw-device addresses

Tags: debian, ipv6, vlan, ipv4

Setting up a cluster with a private IPv4 VLAN, we have the following problem:

IP A says:

```
 3: eno1.4000@eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [our mac] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno1.4000
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet [our public ip v4] peer x.y.z.a/32 scope global eno1.4000
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 /64 scope global
       valid_lft [first ipv6-adress] forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 [second ipv6 address]/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can we remove the raw-device-IP-addresses from the VLAN-device? This is our /etc/network/interfaces:

```
 auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
 address[our publiv ipv4 address]/32
 gateway [ip v4 gateway]

# VLAN with ID 4000 for internal Cluster network data
auto eno1.4000
iface eno1.4000 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1/24
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  vlan-raw-device eno1
  mtu 1400
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like someone's misconfiguration. Use the `ip address del [our public ip v4] dev  eno1.4000` to remove this address from vlan interface.